# Adding soap headers in apache camel

Tags: wso2, soapheader

I am calling a soap web service from Apache Camel, which is having header (for authentication) and the body. My Dataformat is POJO (tried with PAYLOAD too) Nothing got succeeded.

echange.getIn().setHeader() is not working (Checking the request using tcpmon)

Any suggestion or coding will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html
Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ankush sono. But this will be adding the header in the transport level. I wanted to add in the soap envelop.

Comment: The issue has been resolved. I have added the Content-Type as text/xml and SOAPAction headers. It works fine as expected.

Comment: i am having similar problem, should this content-Type be as part of camel-context ?